# NLP - identifying which adjective describes which noun in a sentence

Tags: nlp, text-mining

I need a method / algorithm for identifying which adjective describes which noun in a sentence.

Sample input:

```
"The product itself is good however this company has a terrible service"
```

As an output i'd like to get something like:

```
[product, good]
[service, terrible]
```

Could you please point me to some resources / names / algorithms or libraries (no matter which programming language) that might help with solving this?

Comment: I have already received a satisfying answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741729/nlp-identifying-which-adjective-describes-which-noun-in-a-sentence

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted and already answered.